# How to add data entry by using Auth

Tags: php, laravel-8

How can I add data entry by using Auth? The `id` works fine, but the `entry` doesn't work. Why?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'day' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required'
    ]);

    $post = post::create([
        'user_id' => $id = Auth::id(),
        'day' => $request->day,
        'date' => $request->date,
        'nots' => $request->nots,
        'entry' => $entry = Auth::user()
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()
}
```

Comment: What value you want to insert for `entry` column?

Comment: name of the person entering the data  ( text)

Comment: So it should be `'entry' => Auth::user()->name`

Comment: @nice_dev thanks for your help but column 'entry' still empty

Comment: What is the column name in your user table then?

Comment: Column name "name "

Comment: Then it has to work. Can you share a minimum reproducible example so that I could check on my machine?

Comment: Ok, maybe I figured it out. Add 'entry' column to $fillable array in Post model file.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution...Thank you for your help :)